# How to increase load on stateful application in kubernetes cluster using a script

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-analysis, kubernetes-pod, replicaset, horizontal-scaling

I have implemented horizontal pod autoscaler for my stateful application. How can I increase the load on this application do that my CPU utilisation goes up and pods are autoscaled

Answer (score 0):

- you can use [Kubernetes performance testing tutorial: Load test a cluster](https://searchitoperations.techtarget.com/tutorial/Kubernetes-performance-testing-tutorial-Load-test-a-cluster) as an example how to perform load test on cluster
- you can use [kubernetes-jmeter](https://github.com/kaarolch/kubernetes-jmeter) to generate workloads to achieve load testing
- you can write script using any lang you know to generate a load

In any case, I would like to recommend you start from [13-Step Guide to Performance Testing in Kubernetes](https://dzone.com/articles/performance-testing-in-kubernetes) to check how you can setup performance testing with monitoring